# Probability - comparison 6-sided dices

Tags: python, probability, dice

I am in new probability. Please have me.
We have 3 identical 6-sided dices. We role one dice first and the remaining 2 dices after that. What is the probability that the point obtained in the first roll is greater than the sum of points obtained in the second roll?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Comment: how is that tagged as Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the total number of possibilities is quite small, 6**3, we can simply enumerate them all and count the number of events we are interested in:

```
import itertools as IT

hits = 0
for roll in IT.product(range(1,7), repeat=3):
    if roll[0] > roll[1] + roll[2]:
        hits += 1
        print(roll, roll[1]+roll[2])
total = 6**3
print('Probability of first roll > sum of 2 rolls: {}/{} ~= {:.2%}'
      .format(hits,total,hits/total))
```

reports

```
Probability of first roll > sum of 2 rolls: 20/216 ~= 9.26%
```

(Corrected based on [Aniket Rangrej's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50657059/190597)).

Answer (score 0):

```
Dice1 > sum(Dice2, Dice3) combination
1 > NA
2 > NA
3 > (1,1)
4 > (1,1),(1,2),(2,1)
5 > (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(1,3),(3,1)
6 > (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(1,3),(3,1),(1,4),(4,1),(2,3),(3,2)

prob = 20/36*6 
prob = approx 0.09
```